# Access fields dynamically in a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-field, dynamic-apex

I need to use dynamic fields in a for loop so that i can pick up the values from different field on insertion of an object accordingly.

Below mentioned are the fields which needs to be dynamically accessed.

[image]

Is there a way where we can use something like `Target_Name_[i]__c` in the loop so that on every iteration it picks up the respective field value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `SObject` class has dynamic `get` methods that allow you to specify a string. You could, for example, do something like:

```
for (MyObject__c record : trigger.new)
{
    for (Integer i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            String target = (String)record.get('Target_Name_' + i + '__c');
            if (target == null) break;
            Object targetValue = record.get(target);
            // further processing...
        }
        catch (SObjectException e)
        {
            // target field not defined
            // validate using addError?
        }
    }
}
```